# IPv6 autoconfigure on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, ipv6

I read this from [Running IPv6](http://www.runningipv6.net/):

```
C:\>netsh
netsh>interface ipv6
netsh interface ipv6>show addres
Querying active state...
Interface 6: Local Area Connection 3
Addr Type  DAD State  Valid Life   Pref. Life   Address
---------  ---------- ------------ ------------ -----------------------------
Temporary  Preferred   6d23h38m55s     23h36m8s     2001:db8:1dde:1:6d16:9d1:b1ec:2245
Public     Preferred  29d23h59m30s  6d23h59m30s 2001:db8:1dde:1:201:2ff:fe29:23b6
Link       Preferred      infinite     infinite fe80::201:2ff:fe29:23b6
```

The books says, after IPv6 is enabled on XP, auto configure will give it 3 addresses, a **Link**, a **Public**, and a **Temporary** one.

But on my computer, I could only see **Link**, what was the problem?

Comment: I tried running the same command in Windows 7 and I only got **Public** + a lot of **Other**

Comment: I only got a "Link", ipv6 is quite complicated than I thought.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have a DHCPv6 server available so you are only getting a link local address by default. The auto-configuration process for IPv6 requires these link local addresses at a minimum, the other addresses are added as later steps in the auto-configuration process complete.

See http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_IPv6AutoconfigurationandRenumbering.htm for a description of the process.